# Why does it seem ACF the_field() is requiring the Post ID?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have used ACF on a lot of projects, but I am running into an odd bug.  When I try to display some field value with `the_field()` in the loop it seems to need the second parameter, even though that second parameter is supposed to default to the current post's ID.  Can you help with an explanation or solution?

This example doesn't display anything

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'events' ) );

if ($query->have_posts()) {
  while ($query->have_posts()) {
    $query->the_post();
    the_field('event_date'); 
  }                   
}
```

This example works

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'events' ) );

if ($query->have_posts()) {
  while ($query->have_posts()) {
    $query->the_post();
    $id = get_the_ID();
    the_field('event_date', $id); 
  }                   
}
```